# Como colocar menu responsivo para sobrepor

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

Olá, como faço para colocar esse menu responsivo para aparecer na frente?

```
<header class="box-header">
            <div class="box-topo">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><h1></h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-menu">
                <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" >
                <label class="btn-menu" for="btn-menu">&#9776;</label>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Página Inicial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#perfil">Profissional</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#projetos">Projetos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#certificados">Certificados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>


@media screen and (max-width: 640px){

    #btn-menu{
    } 

    .btn-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .box-topo{
    }

    .box-header{
    }


    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu{
        margin-right: 0%;
    }

    .menu{
        margin-top: 2%;
        background-color: #363563;
        width: 55%;
        margin-right: -100%;
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .menu ul{
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: static;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .4s;

    }

    .menu ul li{
        margin-left: 4%;
        float: none;
    }

    .menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }
```

Comment: Falta colocar o HTML

Comment: @Sveen coloquei

Comment: Esse elemento que está por cima do menu é oq? Uma div fixa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `z-index` só vai fazer efeito se o elemento tiver `position`:

> The `z-index` CSS property specifies the z-order of a **positioned** element
>   and its descendants[...]
>
> *A propriedade `z-index` especifica a ordem-z de um elemento **posicionado** e seus descendentes.*

- [Documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Insira `position: relative;` na classe `.menu` que resolve o problema:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 840px){

    #btn-menu{
    } 

    .btn-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .box-topo{
    }

    .box-header{
    }


    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu{
        margin-right: 0%;
    }

    .menu{
        margin-top: 2%;
        background-color: #363563;
        width: 55%;
        margin-right: -100%;
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
        z-index: 999;
        position: relative;
    }

    .menu ul{
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: static;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .4s;

    }

    .menu ul li{
        margin-left: 4%;
        float: none;
    }

    .menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header class="box-header">
            <div class="box-topo">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><h1>Isaque Saraiva</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-menu">
                <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" >
                <label class="btn-menu" for="btn-menu">&#9776;</label>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Página Inicial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#perfil">Profissional</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#projetos">Projetos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#certificados">Certificados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
<main style="position: fixed; background: red;">
ashsag ashgasg assag ashgsah asgsahg hsag hash ashsag sahagsh sahgasgashgas ash sahgsah sah sahgsah gsah hsagsahgsah gahsghsa sahas hsa ghas 
</main>
```

## Veja abaixo que sem position o z-index não funciona:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 840px){

    #btn-menu{
    } 

    .btn-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .box-topo{
    }

    .box-header{
    }


    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu{
        margin-right: 0%;
    }

    .menu{
        margin-top: 2%;
        background-color: #363563;
        width: 55%;
        margin-right: -100%;
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
        z-index: 999;
        /* position: relative; */
    }

    .menu ul{
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: static;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .4s;

    }

    .menu ul li{
        margin-left: 4%;
        float: none;
    }

    .menu ul li a{
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header class="box-header">
            <div class="box-topo">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><h1>Isaque Saraiva</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-menu">
                <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" >
                <label class="btn-menu" for="btn-menu">&#9776;</label>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Página Inicial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#perfil">Profissional</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#projetos">Projetos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#certificados">Certificados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
<main style="position: fixed; background: red;">
ashsag ashgasg assag ashgsah asgsahg hsag hash ashsag sahagsh sahgasgashgas ash sahgsah sah sahgsah gsah hsagsahgsah gahsghsa sahas hsa ghas 
</main>
```

Comment: Quando o botão não está em checked o box do menu fica do lado aparecendo um scroll na página como faço para retirar?

Comment: Quando o botão não está em checked o box do menu fica do lado aparecendo um scroll na página como faço para retirar?

Comment: Acho que já entendi... perai que vou ver

Comment: Melhor, coloque no html um overflow-x hidden: `html{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}`

Comment: Deu certo?.....

Comment: Opa! Deu certo... 
Agradeço pela sua ajuda. Mas um aprendizado! :D

Comment: Nâo deu mais certo?